# How do i know if an activity has been deleted or repositioned in the workflow designer?

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

How do i know if an activity has been deleted or repositioned in the workflow designer? the unloaded event of the activity fires on both occasions

Answer (score 2):

Dave's answer is partial correct. When you move your activity a remove event is also called, so that verification will be true for both cases. I use the activity's modelItem.Parent. 
modelItem.Parent is null when the activity is actually deleted, and != null when it's just moved.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find out if an activity has been deleted by using the following event:

```
ModelService ms = workflowdesigner.Context.Services.GetService<ModelService>();
ms.ModelChanged += new EventHandler<ModelChangedEventArgs>(Designer_ModelServiceChanged);
```

You can then find the deleted activities by doing something like:

```
private void Designer_ModelChanged( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
           //iterate through model items and find your activity
           if (null != eventArgs.ItemsRemoved)
           {
                foreach (ModelItem mi in eventArgs.ItemsRemoved)
                {
                    //find your activity
                }
            }
}
```

Check out the book Pro WF Windows Workflow in .NET 4 by Bruce Bukovics